# Preventing or suppressing Microsoft log entries?

Tags: .net-core, nlog, minimal-apis

I'm using .NET 6 minimal APIs for a web service.  I have NLog configured and working well using "appsettings.json" by using this:

```
builder.Services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{
    loggingBuilder.AddNLog(new NLogLoggingConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetSection("NLog")));
});
```

I'm logging to a database, but I don't want the messages from Microsoft (e.g. "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" and "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics").  There seem to be a lot of similar questions about this, but the vast majority use "NLog.config".  I haven't found a solution that works using "appsettings.json".  According to everything I've read, this should be trivial using a rule something like the following:

```
{
  "logger": "Microsoft.*",
  "finalMinLevel": "Error"
}
```

However this does not work for me.

The only thing I've gotten to work is to "filter in" the namespace I want, rather than filtering out the ones I don't.  For example, rather than

```
{
  "logger": "*",
  "minLevel": "Information",
  "writeTo": "database"
}
```

I use

```
{
  "logger": "myNamespace.*",
  "minLevel": "Information",
  "writeTo": "database"
}
```

This is clearly not my preference.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The credit for this answer needs to go to Rolf.  He said the order of the rules matters, and with that advice I solved my problem.  My rules now look like this, and it works exactly as I'd been wanting.

```
"rules": [
  {
    "logger": "Microsoft.*",
    "finalMinLevel": "Warn"
  },
  {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "Information",
    "writeTo": "database"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice that NLog v5 introduce the following breaking change [NLog.Extensions.Logging without any filter](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter)

You can explict specify `RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter = false` for the NLog-options-input-parameter for `AddNLog`. Alternative you can specify `RemoveLoggerFactoryFilter` for the `"NLog"` logger in appsettings.json. Yet another alternative is to use `finalMinLevel` in the NLog-Logging-Rules.

When using `finalMinLevel` then it is important that they are placed in top of the `"rules": []`-array, so they will block the LogEvents from reaching the other rule-items below.

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json

Comment: Whereas I appreciate the effort, I have stated in my original post (explicitly, I thought) that this isn't working for me.

Comment: @BradleyPlett Think you have to provide a complete appsettings.json example, and not just small snippets. Since the order of NLog Logging Rules are important. Ex. NLog-Logging-Rules with `finalMinLevel` should be placed first (As shown in the [first link](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter) about the breaking change)

Comment: @BradleyPlett Also a good idea to enable `"throwConfigExceptions": true` to verify that NLog-configuration is parsed succesfully.

Comment: Problem solved - thank-you Rolf!!!  Your statement saying "the order of NLog Logging Rules are important. Ex. NLog-Logging-Rules with finalMinLevel should be placed first" is what solved it for me.  I was putting the "finalMinLevel" rule last.